# How do i convert a list to multiple comma separated strings?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm experimenting with win10toast library and i'm tring to figure out a way to feed a function a list of sentences by somehow separating the list with commas and quotes around each string.

```
testtoast = ['foo', 'boo', 'bar']
arr = ','.join(testtoast)
print(arr)
Output: 'foo, boo, bar'
```

However, my desired output needs to look like:
    'foo', 'boo', 'bar'

I need the output string to be multiple strings separated by commas

Comment: *I need the output string to be multiple strings separated by commas* ... a `str`ing can not be a sequence of strings at the same time. what is your desired output datatype?

Comment: My desired output datatype is for the list to convert to multiple strings, not a single one. i might've written it in a confusing way, i edited the description now.

Comment: *multiple strings* as in a `list` of strings? *multiple strings* is not an available datatype... `testtoast` is just a `list` of  strings already. if you are concerned about the output only you could try this: `print(*(repr(i) for i in testtoast), sep=',')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow below approach;

```
testtoast = ['foo', 'boo', 'bar']
testtoast = ["'" + testelem + "'" for testelem in testtoast]
arr = ','.join(testtoast)
print(arr)
```

Output will be as 'foo','boo','bar'